# Comparison of to two repartitions and repeated measure on an uneven population: limits of a McNemar

Tags: r, limit, chi-squared, contingency

I am working in linguistics on the transformation of one sound in specific contexts: for example, the number of [s] produced [s] or transformed in nouns, and pronouns (I am copying you a part of my code below).

For now, I am using a McNemar test, but I am worried about the limits of this test because the 459 occurrences of  [s] in a noun and the 53 in pronouns have been produced unevenly by 16 children only... What bias does it create? Would there be a better test or an adaptation to this one to take into account the number of a child?
Thank you for your time and answer
Sincerely
Sarah

```
tableaus = matrix(c(292,167,31,22),byrow = TRUE,ncol=2)
tableaus
###nommer les colonnes et les lignes
rownames(tableaus)=c("lexemes","pronouns") 
colnames(tableaus)=c("Accurate","+/- transformed")
tableaus
##Chi2
mcnemar.test(tableaus, correct = FALSE)
```

Comment: The major threat to validity is not from bias, but rather from the lack of independence of the trials. Also, McNemar's test is for paired data and I see no description that indicates your design had any pairing. I think the best place for this question AFTER clarification of the study design and statement of hypothesis being tested would be stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=clustered+2x2+tables

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
For me the data are paired as the same individu can produce both transformed and not transformed sounds... But may be I got it wrong...

Comment: Designs where one of two possible outcomes are recorded are “binomial”, not “paired”. Again, I believe a more complete description of the study design and data gathering should be discussed with a statistician.